Is the real span of symmetric product states equal to the set of Hermitians with image in the symmetric space?
It is easy to see that the real span of the set of product states is equal to the set of Hermitian operators (see e.g Can every bipartite state be written as $\rho_{AB} = \sum_{ij} c_{ij}\sigma_A^i\otimes \omega_B^j$?). My question is whether an analogous property holds for symmetric product states.
Below, $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose.
Question: Is it true that the real span
$$ S:= \text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{(vv^*)^{\otimes m} : v \in \mathbb{C}^d\} $$
is equal to the set of Hermitian operators whose image is contained in the symmtric space $S^m(\mathbb{C}^d)\subseteq (\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes m}$? In other words, is it true that for every symmetric vector $\psi \in S^m(\mathbb{C}^d)$, it holds that $\psi \psi^* \in S$?

You might also be interested in quantum de Finetti theorems. (And it might well be that the literature on the topic also contains some hint about your question.)

Theorem 7.5 of Watrous' book (https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI) might be of interest (though I don't think it's the same statement)

@glS 7.5 is the pure-state version of the statement (i.e. every vector in the sym. space is is of the form $\int d\phi c_\phi \lvert\phi\rangle^{\otimes n}$.
